# textinput values are not updated

Tags: python, kivy

Why the textinput value isn't updated with this code? I need to capture the value typed by the user when I click on the button, but no matter what it seems that I can only get the default text.

This is a runnable example on python 3.4.3:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from functools import partial 

class TestApp(App):
    def check(self, texto, *args):
        print(texto)

    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        txtinput = TextInput(background_color=(1,1,1,1),
                                   font_size=16,
                                   size_hint=(None, None),
                                   size=(200, 35),
                                   pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "bottom":0.8},
                                   multiline=False,
                                   text="write here...",
                                   use_bubble=True)
        boton = Button(size_hint=(None, None),
                              size=(150, 50),
                              pos_hint={"left":1, "bottom":1},
                              text="Check",
                              on_release=partial(self.check, txtinput.text))
        layout.add_widget(txtinput)
        layout.add_widget(boton)
        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

I'd like a pure Python answer, I don't really like to use kv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind `check` method with with [TextInput.bind()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example) to your `txtinput` after creation `txtinput` :

```
txtinput = TextInput(background_color=(1,1,1,1), ...
txtinput.bind(text=self.check)
```

And input value became available in code snippet provided in question.

Currently check method is **instance method** and i suppose it always accept instance of `App` as first attribute, txtinput as second and input text as third.

To access your text in `check` method signature shall be updated to that one:

```
def check(self, txt_input, texto, *args):
    print(texto)
```

Comment: not really, it should print "this is not working" when I click on the button, but instead is printing an object when I type on the txtinput. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/aezy94

Comment: @Saelyth ohh that's related to param passing, see updated answer.

Comment: Also i've updated  `txtinput.bind(text=check)` to `txtinput.bind(text=self.check)`

Comment: Now it works, even though I don't understand how. I'll do some tests to figure it out. Thank you :D

Comment: You are welcome :)  You can take a look on that SO Question to extend python knowledge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python